# Find $g'\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ for the following conditions.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Given that for each a$\in(0, 1)$ $\lim_{h\to0^{+}}\int_{h}^{1-h}t^{-a}(1-t)^{a-1}dt$
exists. Let this limit be $g(a)$. $g\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)=\pi$. In addition, it is given that the function $g(a)$ is differentiable on $(0, 1)$. Find $g'\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$

Here are my multiple attempts:-

**Attempt $1$:**

$$I_1=\int_{h}^{1-h}t^{-a}(1-t)^{a-1}dt$$

$$I_1=\int_{h}^{1-h}(1-t)^{-a}t^{a-1}dt$$

$$I_1=\int_{h}^{1-h}\left(t^{-a}(1-t)^{a-1}+(1-t)^{-a}t^{a-1}\right)dt$$

$$I_1=\int_{h}^{1-h}\left(\dfrac{(1-t)^{a-1}}{t^a}+\dfrac{t^{a-1}}{(1-t)^{a}}\right)dt$$

$$I_1=\int_{h}^{1-h}\dfrac{(1-t)^{2a-1}+t^{2a-1}}{t^a(1-t)^a}dt$$

Now from here I was not able to take it further.

**Attempt $2$:**

Integrating by parts:-

$$I_1=\int_{h}^{1-h}t^{-a}(1-t)^{a-1}dt$$

$$I_1=-\left(\left(\dfrac{t^{-a}(1-t)^{a}}{a}\right)_{x=1-h}-\left(\dfrac{t^{-a}(1-t)^{a}}{a}\right)_{x=h}\right)-\int_{h}^{1-h}t^{-a-1}(1-t)^adt$$

Now again we are stuck because of second integration.

**Attempt $3$:**

$$g'\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)=\lim_{\delta\to 0}\dfrac{g\left(\dfrac{1}{2}+\delta\right)-g\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)}{\delta}$$

$$g'\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)=\lim_{\delta\to 0}\dfrac{\lim_{h\to0^{+}}\int_{h}^{1-h}\dfrac{t^{-\delta}(1-t)^{\delta}}{\sqrt{t}\sqrt{1-t}}dt-\pi}{\delta}$$

We have $\dfrac{0}{0}$ form here

$$\sqrt{1-t}=y$$
$$-2dy=\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t}}$$

$$g'\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)=\lim_{\delta\to 0}\dfrac{\lim_{h\to0^{+}}-2\displaystyle\int_{\sqrt{1-h}}^{\sqrt{h}}\dfrac{(1-y^2)^{-\delta}(y)^{2\delta}}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}dy-\pi}{\delta}$$

$$g'\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)=\lim_{\delta\to 
0}\dfrac{\lim_{h\to0^{+}}-2\displaystyle\int_{\sqrt{1-h}}^{\sqrt{h}}\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{1}{y^2}-1\right)^{-\delta}}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}dy-\pi}{\delta}$$

Now here I was not able to proceed further with integration.

Comment: any suggestions here?